# Time Domain Analysis with Vector Network Analyzer

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave, time, reflection, vna

I have done some measurements with a VNA in time domain (by using the transform operation of the instrument). Precisely, I have selected the measurement of S11 (reflection coefficient at port 1 of the VNA) while leaving port 1 open, and I selected the Step Response Mode.

The result of my measurement is this one:

[image]

My question is: which is precisely the quantity on y axis? I think it is the reflected signal: in fact port 1 is open and so there is total reflection, and therefore we see exactly the voltage step that the instrument has sent to port 1. And if we look at the instrument display, we see that it is measured in Volt, so it is a voltage signal.

But I have set the measurement of S11: why do I get a measure in volt? I thought that it may be due to the fact that the reflected signal is proportional to S11 (Vreflected = S11 * Vincident), but I am not sure since S11 is function of frequency, so parts of the signal with different frequencies are multiplied by different coefficient.

Comment: S11 in time domain can be expressed in different ways. What did you set the instrument to display?

Comment: Real part of S11, linear scale. The amplitude values I visualized in the instrument were expressed in volt

Comment: Mmm. Try plotting the magnitude - abs(Re+jIm) and it will make more sense. Also, why step mode and not impulse?